# How to check a list (Of T) if it contains an item, but ignoring if one property is different?

Tags: vb.net, contains

So I have a struct that is called alarm, and a list of alarms called alarmList. I go through a loop to see if there are any new alarms. If the List of alarms already has it, I say ignore it and continue:

```
Dim alarms() = G4TAPIs.G4TGetActivity(MyActRequest)  'get updated list of alarms
'this list may include all of the alarms previously. 

For Each alarm In alarms
    'if acknowledged, don't show
    If alarm.AckedFlag = True And alarm.ResetFlag = True Then   
        Continue For
    End If

    If alarmList.Contains(alarm) Then
        Continue For
    End If

    'do stuff to process

    alarmList.add(alarm)  'add new alarm
Next
```

What happens is this guy in called regularly. Alarms() is updated with ALL past alarms, including the ones I already processed, but it updates their time to the current time, despite them already having happened. So i check to see if they're already processed on my list with contains.

Is there a way (linq methods are welcomed as well!) to edit the contains condition so that it ignores one feature if it is different? Particularly alarm.when (a Date type variable). It updates to the current date, and I want to make sure that the contains list checks to see if they're equal in all instances BUT the .when.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you willing to override the default equality comparator?

Comment: (shrug) Sure. Just curious to see what options are out there.

Comment: The [`IEnumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method can take a predicate that can do any comparison you want.

Answer (score 2):

Create an IEqualityComparer that ignores the property you don't want to check, and use the overloaded Contains that accepts the value and an IEqualityComparer.

Sorry - this is c#, not VB... I rarely write VB, and if I tried - it would likely be very ugly.

```
class AlarmEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Alarm>
{
    public bool Equals(Alarm a1, Alarm a2)
    {
        // check whatever properties you want
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Alarm a1)
    {
        // build a hashcode using the properties that are checked
    }
}
```

Edit... VB translation added.

```
Class AlarmEqualityComparer
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Alarm)

    Public Function Equals(a1 As Alarm, a2 As Alarm) As Boolean
        ' Check whatever properties you want
    End Function

    Public Function GetHashCode(a1 As Alarm) As Integer
        ' Build a hashcode using the properties that are checked
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: No worries! I get the concept.